# How to style Directory Listings XAMPP

Tags: css, apache, xampp

So using XAMPP, it shows a list of folders and files that are hosted locally on my machine. So far, it shows all of these directories in a simple, plain list. What I'd like to do is to be able to use CSS to style it. This may sound confusing so here's some images explaining what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

to...

[image]

It is possible to do this because I downloaded a theme for it a while back, I am having trouble trying to find it again so I was windering, if someone out there knows where it is, it would be much appreciated if you would send me the link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tutorial devoted to customizing directory listings:
http://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/

It shows exact what actions to perform in order to customize it. So shouldn't be too hard to follow.

Sadly, I'm unable to find the style you provided. So I will update this reply in-case I have.

Here are some other nice directory listing styles:

- https://github.com/meodai/mod_autoindex.oh
- http://adamwhitcroft.com/apaxy/
- https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mod_autoindex&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults

Comment: The style I provided was a simlple mockup made by me to demonstrate what I wanted to do! :) All I know about the style that I used to have before was that it was very modern, flat looking! Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are very welcome. I've also included a few styles I managed to find.. Pretty awesome looking ones if you ask me :) First one is my favorite ^^

Comment: You've found the style I was looking for! It was Apaxy! Thanks a bunch!:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in functionality of Apache’s mod_autoindex module to style and enhance your default directory views.

You can go through this [link](http://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/)

It has a very detailed description for changing and customizing the views the way you want them to be.

You can customize the icons as well as the css.